# Excel VBA/Macro Loop through Columns and Sort Each Column Independently by Color & then Remove Cells with Background Color

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am a complete newbie when it comes to VBA. I am hoping that someone will take pity on me and help me to create the code of my dreams!

I am trying to loop through columns and sort them based on background color. The columns should always be sorted from top to bottom as: no color, green, orange, & grey. Each column differs in length. Each column does not always contain all colors. The number of columns also changes (based on the month). There is text in the cells, but the text does not matter.

The data is on "Sheet1" and I would like the data to remain the same on "Sheet1" but copy the updated sorted data to "Sheet2".

This is how Sheet 1 and 2 should look.

[image: 1]

Once the updated sorted data has been added to "Sheet2", I would like to remove all cells that have background color. (i.e. The background color & text would be deleted & and only the original cells with no background w/text would remain.)

Again, I would like the "Sheet2" data to remain the same and copy the updated data onto "Sheet3".

This is how Sheet 2 and 3 should look.

[image: 2]

The only code I have is based off of a Macro I created to sort column A by background color.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A26:A41").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A26:A41" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A26:A41"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(146, _
        208, 80)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A26:A41"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
        192, 0)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A26:A41"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(128, _
        128, 128)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A26:A41")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Notes on the code created by Tim Williams. The code changes the background color of cells. The link below shows an example. On the left, is the original starting point and after running the code, the background colors are in different locations (the right). The rest of the code works wonderfully.
[Results of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKpS0.png)

Comment: Is sheet 2 just an intermediate step, or does it serve some other purpose?

Comment: I guess, at the end of the day, Sheet 2 is just an intermediate step. However, it is a nice graphic visualization of the data. But if it's easier to go from sheet 1 directly to sheet 3, then that is fine too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, rng As Range, c As Range, colors, rngCol As Range
    
    colors = Array(RGB(128, 128, 128), RGB(146, 208, 80), RGB(255, 192, 0))
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    
    ws2.Cells.Clear 'clear previous work
    ws3.Cells.Clear
    
    Set rng = ws1.Range("C1", ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) 'headers
    i = 1
    'loop down and find the end of the longest column
    Do While Application.CountA(rng.Offset(i)) > 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Set rng = rng.Resize(i) 'resize to last occupied row
    
    'AddCellColors rng.Offset(1), colors 'for testing only...
    
    Set c = ws2.Range("A1")
    rng.Copy c
    'loop over the date headers and sort each data column on color
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        If Len(c.Offset(1).Value) > 0 Then 'any data below this header?
            Set rngCol = ws2.Range(c.Offset(1), ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp))
            SortRangeOnColor rngCol, colors
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(0, 1) 'next header
    Loop
    
    ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy ws3.Range("A1") 'copy to sheet3
    'loop and clear all colored cells
    For Each c In ws3.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then c.Clear
    Next c
    
End Sub

'sort range `rng` on array of colors `arrColors`
Sub SortRangeOnColor(rng As Range, arrColors)
    Dim i As Long
    With rng.Worksheet.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            For i = LBound(arrColors) To UBound(arrColors)
                .Add(rng, xlSortOnCellColor, xlDescending, , xlSortNormal). _
                                         SortOnValue.Color = arrColors(i)
            Next i
        End With
        .SetRange rng
        .header = xlNo
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

'for testing only - add colors from array to cells in range `rng`
'  some cells are left uncolored
'Sub AddCellColors(rng As Range, arrColors)
'    Dim c As Range, indx, ub
'    ub = UBound(arrColors)
'    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
'    For Each c In rng.Cells
'        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
'            indx = Application.RandBetween(0, UBound(arrColors) + 2)
'            If indx <= ub Then c.Interior.Color = arrColors(indx)
'        End If
'    Next c
'End Sub
```

Comment: I updated my question with a link to a picture of what it looks like before and after running the code. The code seems to randomly change the location of the background cell color on Sheet 1. Other than that, the code works wonderfully!

Comment: Comment out that line `AddCellColors rng.Offset(1), colors 'for testing only...`  I was using that (and the called sub) to create randomly-colored test data sets while working on the code.  You likely do not need that...

Comment: Commenting out the line worked! I did notice when sorting, your code `colors = Array(RGB(128, 128, 128), RGB(146, 208, 80), RGB(255, 192, 0))` sorted it as no color, orange, green, grey. So I edited it to `colors = Array(RGB(128, 128, 128), RGB(255, 192, 0), RGB(146, 208, 80))` and it then sorted in the correct order of no color, green, orange, grey. One other request. I forgot that my Sheet 1 data actually starts in column C. And of course when I ran the code, it did not like that. Any tweaks to fix that?

Comment: `Set rng = ws1.Range("C1").CurrentRegion`

Comment: I had tried changing it from A1 to C1 prior to asking, but that prevented it from sorting the columns on Sheet2. But it still removed the colored cells from Sheet3.

Comment: Well you have to adjust all the rest of the code accordingly...

Comment: If your layout is different from your screenshots then other adjustments may be needed.  There's no way for me to know what your actual data looks like.  Eg `CurrentRegion` only works here if there's no other data "touching" the data you want to work on.

Comment: Yes, when I submitted the question I forgot that my data started in column C. There is data in both column A & B, but that does not need to be sorted and it does not need to be transferred to Sheet 2 or 3. Column A & B will be varying lengths.

Comment: Is there any existing data on sheets 2 and 3?

Comment: See edits above for how to select from C1

Comment: The edits for selecting from C1 worked.